# Intro to GPU programming

Tags: gpu

Everyone has this huge massively parallelized supercomputer on their desktop in the form of a graphics card GPU.

- What is the "hello world" equivalent of the GPU community?
- What do I do, where do I go, to get started programming the GPU for the major GPU vendors?

-Adam

Comment: Are you talking about GPGPU, or graphics coding?

Comment: He's talking about CUDA (an API for nVidia GPUs) and other techniques. Using the FPU units available in GPUs for non-graphics coding.

Comment: For reference, a last generation GeForce 8800 has 128 stream processors operating at ~1.3 GHz, a top of the line GTX 280 has 240 stream processors, the theoretical performance of these GPUs is 0.5 and 0.9 TeraFLOPS, respectively.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Check out CUDA by NVidia, IMO it's the easiest platform to do GPU programming. There are tons of cool materials to read.
[http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home.html][1]
[1]: http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home.html

Hello world would be to do any kind of calculation using GPU.

Answer (score 18):

1. You get programmable vertex and
   pixel shaders that allow execution 
   of code directly on the GPU to
   manipulate the buffers that are to
   be drawn. These languages (i.e.
   OpenGL's GL Shader Lang and High
   Level Shader Lang and DirectX's equivalents
   ), are C style syntax, and really
   easy to use. Some examples of HLSL
   can be found [here](http://www.riemers.net/) for XNA game
   studio and Direct X. I don't have
   any decent GLSL references, but I'm
   sure there are a lot around. These
   shader languages give an immense
   amount of power to
   manipulate what gets drawn at a per-vertex
   or per-pixel level, directly
   on the graphics card, making things
   like shadows, lighting, and bloom
   really easy to implement.
2. The second thing that comes to mind is using
   [openCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) to code for the new
   lines of general purpose GPU's. I'm
   not sure how to use this, but my
   understanding is that openCL gives
   you the beginnings of being able to
   access processors on both the
   graphics card and normal cpu. This is not mainstream technology yet, and seems to be driven by Apple.
3. [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home.html) seems to be a hot topic. CUDA is nVidia's way of accessing the GPU power. [Here](http://www.gpgpu.org/asplos2008/) are some intros

Answer (score 9):

I think the others have answered your second question. As for the first, the "Hello World" of CUDA, I don't think there is a set standard, but personally, I'd recommend a parallel adder (i.e. a programme that sums N integers).

If you look the "reduction" example in the NVIDIA SDK, the superficially simple task can be extended to demonstrate numerous CUDA considerations such as coalesced reads, memory bank conflicts and loop unrolling.

See this presentation for more info:

http://www.gpgpu.org/sc2007/SC07_CUDA_5_Optimization_Harris.pdf

Answer (score 8):

[OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/) is an effort to make a cross-platform library capable of programming code suitable for, among other things, GPUs.  It allows one to write the code without knowing what GPU it will run on, thereby making it easier to use some of the GPU's power without targeting several types of GPU specifically.  I suspect it's not as performant as native GPU code (or as native as the GPU manufacturers will allow) but the tradeoff can be worth it for some applications.

It's still in its relatively early stages (1.1 as of this answer), but has gained some traction in the industry - for instance it is natively supported on OS X 10.5 and above.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the [ATI Stream Computing SDK](http://ati.amd.com/technology/streamcomputing/sdkdwnld.html). It is based on [BrookGPU](http://graphics.stanford.edu/projects/brookgpu/) developed at Stanford.

In the future all GPU work will be standardized using [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL). It's an Apple-sponsored initiative that will be graphics card vendor neutral.

Answer (score 6):

CUDA is an excellent framework to start with. It lets you write GPGPU kernels in C. The compiler will produce GPU microcode from your code and send everything that runs on the CPU to your regular compiler. It is NVIDIA only though and only works on 8-series cards or better. You can check out [CUDA zone](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home.html) to see what can be done with it. There are some great demos in the [CUDA SDK](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_get.html). The documentation that comes with the SDK is a pretty good starting point for actually writing code. It will walk you through writing a matrix multiplication kernel, which is a great place to begin.

Answer (score 6):

Another easy way to get into GPU programming, without getting into CUDA or OpenCL, is to do it via [OpenACC](http://www.openacc-standard.org).

OpenACC works like OpenMP, with compiler directives (like `#pragma acc kernels`) to send work to the GPU. For example, if you have a big loop (only larger ones really benefit):

```
int i;
float a = 2.0;
float b[10000];
#pragma acc kernels
for (i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) b[i] = 1.0f;
#pragma acc kernels
for (i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
  b[i] = b[i] * a;
}
```

Edit: unfortunately, only the PGI compiler really supports OpenACC right now, for NVIDIA GPU cards.

Answer (score 4):

Try [GPU++](http://blog.beef.de/thesis/) and [libSh](http://libsh.org/wiki/index.php/How_Sh_Works)

LibSh link has a good description of how they bound the programming language to the graphics primitives (and obviously, the primitives themselves), and GPU++ describes what its all about, both with code examples.

Answer (score 3):

If you use MATLAB, it becomes pretty simple to use GPU's for technical computing (matrix computations and heavy math/number crunching). I find it useful for uses of GPU cards outside of gaming. Check out the link below:

http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gpu.html