# Newbie to GPU programming: what to learn?

Tags: image-processing, gpu

I am rendering a certain scene to an off-screen frame buffer (FBO) and then I'm reading the rendered image using `glReadPixels()` for processing on the CPU. The processing involves some very simple scanning routines and extraction of data.

After profiling I realized that most of what my application does is spend time in `glReadPixels()` - more than 50% of the time. So the natural step is to move the processing to the GPU so that the data would not have to be copied.

So my question is - what would be the best way to program such a thing to the GPU?
GLSL?
CUDA?
Anything else I'm not currently aware of?
The main requirements is that it'll have access to The rendered off-screen frame bufferes (or texture data since it is possible to render to a texture) and to be able to output some information to the CPU, say in the order of 1-2Kb per frame.

Answer (score 3):

You might find the answers in the "[Intro to GPU programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219928/intro-to-gpu-programming)" questions useful.

-Adam

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of pointers to getting started with GPU programming in other questions, but if you have an application that is already built using OpenGL, then probably your question really is "which one will interoperate with OpenGL"?

After all, your whole point is to avoid the overhead of reading your FBO back from the GPU to the CPU with glReadPixels().  If, for example you had to read it back anyway, then copy the data into a CUDA buffer, then transfer it back to the gpu using CUDA APIs, there wouldn't be much point.

So you need a GPGPU package that will take your OpenGL FBO object as an input directly, without any extra copying.

That would probably rule out everything except GLSL.

I'm not 100% sure whether CUDA has any way of operating directly on an OpenGL buffer object, but I don't think it has that feature.

I am sure that ATI's Stream SDK doesn't do that.  (Although it will interoperate with DirectX.)

I doubt that the DirectX 11 "technology preview" with compute shaders has that feature, either.

**EDIT:**  Follow-up: it looks like CUDA, at least the most recent version, has some support for OpenGL interoperability.  If so, that's probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found this [Modern GPU](http://nvlabs.github.io/moderngpu/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may find OpenAI [Triton](https://openai.com/blog/triton/) useful